# Using Directx members between c++\CLI assemblies C3767

Tags: c++-cli, directx

I am trying to call a member function from a C++/CLI assembly from another one, but when I start using DirectX struct I get C3767 error : candidate function not accessib

from Utilities.dll

```
#pragma once

#include "define.h"

namespace Utilities
{
    public ref class Data
    {
    public:
        BOOL CreateBuffer( LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 dev)
        {
            ...
            return TRUE;
        }
    {
}
```

And using it from a renderer

```
#include "Renderer.h"

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    SceneRenderer::SceneRenderer(void)
    {

    }

    void SceneRenderer::Render(LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 dev)
    {
        ...

        m_vbo->CreateBuffer(dev); //error C3767: 'Utilities::Data::CreateBuffer': candidate function(s) not accessible

        ...
    }
}
```

I know that using the address of the device int* (&dev) I can cast back to a LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9, but im looking for a better solution

Answer (score 0):

A managed C++ assembly will not export unmanaged types in its public interface by default. LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 is an unmanaged type, so your CreateBuffer method will be marked private, regardless of the access specifier provided (kind of stupid that the compiller isn't even generating a warning about this).

Use `#pragma make_public` or, better yet, do not use unmanaged types in managed interfaces.

Suggestion: Use slimDx or Xna if you want to use DirectX in managed code. These libraries already provide managed wrappers for everything.

Comment: [SlimDX](http://www.slimdx.org/) or [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/) are the best options today. See [DirectX and .NET](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/12/09/directx-and-net.aspx) for more background.